# Filtering table by dropdown selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dropdown, razor-pages

I have a table that displays a list of files and I want to add in a dropdown that if you select it - it filters the table by the dropdown selection, I'm not sure how to do this and I can't find any tutorials - if this question isn't appropriate please let me know and i'll remove it.

Here is a picture of my table and dropdown:
[image: Table]

When selecting a vendor from the dropdown I want the rows to be filtered by the 4th column along.

Below is the code in my cshtml:

```
@page
@model PurchaseOrdersModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url('hero-range-1.jpg');
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>

<h1 style="color: white">Purchase Orders - Admin</h1>
<p>
    <a asp-page="Create" style="color:white">Create File</a>
</p>
<select asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["demo"])" >
    <option value="" disabled selected> Select a Vendor</option>
</select>
<br />
<table class="table" style="background-color: white">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                PO No. 
            </th>
            <th>
                Haulier
            </th>
            <th>
                Comments
            </th>
            <th>
                Vendor
            </th>
            <th>
                Upload
            </th>
            <th>
                Date Uploaded
            </th>
            <th>Download</th>
            <th>Delete Attachment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Files)
        {
            if (item.FileType == "Purchase Order")
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Haulier)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modeItem => item.Vendor.VendorNo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-page="Upload" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Upload File Attachment</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UploadDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (item.Attachment != null)
                        {
                            <form asp-page-handler="Download" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Download">
                            </form>
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (item.Attachment != null)
                        {
                            <form asp-page-handler="Delete" method="post" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete Attachment">
                            </form>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the code in my Page Model:

```
namespace FarmersPortal.Pages
{
    [Authorize(Roles ="Admin,Purchase Order")]
    public class PurchaseOrdersModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<PurchaseOrdersModel> _logger;
        private readonly filedbContext _context;
        

        public PurchaseOrdersModel(ILogger<PurchaseOrdersModel> logger, filedbContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }   

        public IList<Data.File> Files { get; set; }
        public List<Data.Vendor> Vendores { get; set; }
        public IList<Data.Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> test = new List<SelectListItem>();
            Files = _context.Files.ToList();
            Vendors = _context.Vendors.ToList();
            foreach (var item in Vendors)
            {
                test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.VendorName, Value = item.Id.ToString() });
            }
            ViewData["demo"] = test;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDownloadAsync(int? id)
        {
            var myInv = await _context.Files.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (myInv == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (myInv.Attachment == null)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] byteArr = myInv.Attachment;
                string mimeType = "application/pdf";
                return new FileContentResult(byteArr, mimeType)
                {
                    FileDownloadName = $"{myInv.FileType} {myInv.Number}.pdf"
                };
            }

        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int? id)
        {
            var myInv = await _context.Files.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (myInv == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (myInv.Attachment == null)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                myInv.Attachment = null;
                _context.Update(myInv);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            Files = await _context.Files.ToListAsync();
            return Page();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So what problem are you facing?

Comment: @Dai I'm not sure how to link the selection within the dropdown to the table. I imagine it would be something like:

Comment: `if(selection != null) { display rows where Vendor = selection}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code:

```
<script>
function myFunctionThree()
    {
        // Declare variables
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("vendor");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
<script>
```

and adding the `onchange="myFunctionThree()"` to my `<select>` tag.

Comment: Took this from the w3 schools tutorial on creating a search bar and modified it. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

Answer (score 1):

you can use Jquery to achieve it like below.

```
<select asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["demo"])" id="vendor"> // add id in your dropdown
    <option value="" disabled selected> Select a Vendor</option>
</select>


$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#vendor').on('change',function(){
            location.href="@Url.Action('MethodName', 'Controller', new { vendorId ="+$(this).val()+" })";
         })
});
```

On controller side create a method with your requirements as per below

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MethodName (int vendorId)
{
   var model = dbdataMethod(vendorId);
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: How would I do this without a controller? I'm using razor pages so I only have a Page model not a controller.